# How to show UIactivity indicator fo MPMoviePlayerController in Full screen while streaming Audio from URL

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, audio-streaming, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using MPMoviePlayerController for streaming audio from URL. I set it in Full screen mode for better controls view as

```
        MPMoviePlayerController *audioStreamer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
//[audioStreamer.view  setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
[audioStreamer.view  setFrame:self.view.bounds];

//[self.view addSubview: audioStreamer.view];
[self.view insertSubview:audioStreamer.view belowSubview:HUD.view];
[audioStreamer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

//[audioStreamer.view addSubview:HUD.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self 
                                         selector: @selector(loadStateChanged:) 
                                             name: MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                           object: audioStreamer];

[audioStreamer prepareToPlay];
```

While streaming and preparing for play I want to show UIactivicty Indicator so user thought for loading of audio. Any suggestion or piece of code for activity indicator on view of black screen of MPMoviePlayerController in full screen mode needed.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController already has default ActivityIndicator. Is there any special requirement of yours?? You can show ActivityIndicator before loading of MPMoviePlayer till you are preparing the audio. But after that you have default Indicator given.

Comment: Default indicator is not showing good. While loading my app shows a complete black screen without any default indicator. Is there is any method to set default indicator?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your own for this....

Since this is controller, you can get the view of the `MPMoviePlayerController`. Just create the `UIActivityIndicatorView` and place this on the view of the `MPMoviePlayerController`. Please see code.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(140, 200, 50, 21);
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator release];
```

Stop this indicator once movie starts through its delegate methods.

Comment: @Dshah , Your answer solved my problem. My issue was I wanted to show spinner while the movie loads. If anyone has same problem, please check Dshah's answer above.